# HTML text rendering with Swing components won't respect space between spans

Tags: java, html, css, swing, fonts

I've been struggling with HTML rendering using Java Swing's vanilla components (such as JEditorPane or JTextPane).
This is the Java code:

```
JEditorPane measureComponent = new JEditorPane();
measureComponent.setContentType("text/html");
measureComponent.setText(text);
measureComponent.paint(g2); // g2 is my Graphics context
```

*PS: I'm aware that the **paint** method shouldn't be called directly in normal situations, but this graphic context comes from a reports engine used in the system, not the screen itself.*

I should warn that this code is part of a really, *really* big codebase, but the routine of creating and painting this component is basically contained in this snippet.

The HTML text used as test would be something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>
    <span style="font-size: 8pt;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </span>
    <span style="font-size: 8pt;">Etiam sit amet nunc enim.</span>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Those spans with a font-size set in the style overlap each other in the context I'm at. This is a screenshot of the result with a 8pt font, like in the snippet:

[image: 8pt font]

While messing with the HTML, I checked that the font size of the spans influentiate the space between them. This is with 10pt:

[image: 10pt font]

That way, the space is **bigger** than it should. It seems like a certain size is being expected of the spans in both cases, but the text is occupying a different size.

Now, as expected, this won't happen if I create an empty Swing project and use only the snippet. This code is being executed inside a bigger application.

**My question is**: are there ways to set 'default parameters' to Swing components that could result in something like this? The legacy code I have my hands on is very vast, so it's virtually impossible to dive blindly without knowing what to look for.

Sorry if the question seems rather vague, I'm just looking for something to look for, if that makes any sense.

---

**Edit:** I just noticed that the Graphics context I'm in will render the component with those issues, while putting it in a JFrame and showing in the Swing thread won't. Still not sure what could be; the Graphics object seems pretty straightforward and I can't imagine what would make a change to the way it renders HTML tags differently.

Comment: Turns out the Graphics context passed by parameter by the library we're overriding had a scale matrix applied. That caused this strange behaviour from Java2D text rendering. As I'm not sure **why** Java2D behaves like that, I won't answer the question as this is the central issue.

For now, I decided to reset the scale matrix and scaled the font sizes for the same amount. This is far from optimal, but it's the only solution I found atm.